# Lombok Builder does not work with inner static class

Tags: java, lombok, builder

I am trying to use lombok builder to get rid of all boilerplate code that comes while designing builder pattern.
My use case is to use lombok Builder on static inner class.

```
class EmployeeMapper {  
    
    @lombok.Builder
    public static class Builder {
        String name;
        String age;
    }
}
```

When I try to use this I don't see the builder() method being created.
Do I need to build in my code once after adding the annotations?

Comment: once you know what "compiler post-processor" is - your question becomes obvious. also, this can be enabled at the IDE level